# Adding button to the QGIS toolbar or create my own toolbar

Tags: qgis, python, plugins, pyqgis

I want to create a button and add it to the QGIS toolbar or alternatively create my own toolbar and add the button here.

A plugin should be started when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 12):

You can add icons to the toolbar or menus.  For more info check the [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/index.html).

```
def initGui(self):
    # create action that will start plugin configuration
    self.action = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/testplug/icon.png"), "Test plugin", self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.action.setWhatsThis("Configuration for test plugin")
    self.action.setStatusTip("This is status tip")
    self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)

    # add toolbar button and menu item
    self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu("&Test plugins", self.action)
```